# Add subviews to AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, subview, addsubview

I want to add two subviews to `AppDelegate` one for `mainviewController` and another subview for `UIToolbar`.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.mainViewController = [[[MainViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the app delegate rather than in the view controller?

Comment: I need UIToolbar when my application launches. It will be on every screen through out the application. I want UIToolbar to show automatically in all my other UIViewControllers after attaching it to rootviewcontroller. so that when i flip UIViewController to change to another UIViewController. Only UIViewController should flip not UIToolbar.Right now UIToolbar is also flipping with UIViewController. So that is the reason i want to attach it to the rootviewcontroller. For the Toolbar being display in every view have this option to add two subViews to the AppDelegate.

Comment: Currently i have UIToolbar in MainViewController

 // create the UIToolbar at the bottom of the MainViewController
toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
// size up the toolbar and set its frame
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 425, 320, 40);
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
In all my other UIViewControllers i m adding it like this

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

Comment: Ask yourself why you want this as it doesn't really make sense. Then, ask yourself what object is going to control this "global toolbar". Surely the actions on the toolbar should relate to the view you're on? In which case it should be 1 per view controller anyway.

Comment: uitoolbar have only play rewind stop info buttons

Comment: Yes, and what are they going to be wired up to?

Comment: @mattjgalloway  what's wrong with adding it directly to `UIWindow` (perhaps a special controller will be required, but i don't think it `must` be `UIViewController`) ?

Comment: yeah that what i was doing but thanks so much because i was doubtful that it will work or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add it to your app delegate's `window` (i'd recommend to display a rootViewController in the same manner for iOs 3 support):

```
[self.window addSubview:myToolBar];
[self.window addSubview:self.mainViewController.view];
```

Note, using some animations on the top viewController will not animate the toolbar as it is not this viewController's view subview in that case.

Comment: There's a lot of danger doing things like this such as rotation events will mess things up. It's certainly possible (I do similar things in my apps) but you have to be very careful and it's often best to wrap with something that controls the layout properly when things rotate, animate, etc.

Comment: Also btw, I assume you meant to add the toolbar *after* the view controller's view?

Comment: A-Live Now when i add toolbar as subview to app delegate so then i will create all toolbar items and afterwards addtoolbarbuttons items to the array in the view did load of app delegate or in mainviewcontroller which is rootviewcontroller. have this little confusion

Comment: @mattjgalloway nice catches with rotation and the order. Regarding an order, i would actually subtract the toolbar frame from the view controllers. As for orientation, for now i prefer to make a single orientation apps avoiding all the sorts of issues from the rotated scroll/modal views, your point is very clear and meaningful however.

Comment: @user1120133 you are better to try to understand what `mattjgalloway` was trying to bring here. You are better to create a separate controller class for that shared toolbar, if you have difficulties to make it, you could use a separate UIViewController with only a toolbar on the view, it will have all the custom actions together with some very useful system customization and behavior methods (e.g. rotation-related)

Comment: @A-Live - Really subtract the toolbar frame from the view controllers? Now that is a recipe for disaster. There's many different circumstances where the window will automatically resize its root view controller's view to fit it. So if you do what you suggest, it'll go above the toolbar.

Comment: @mattjgalloway can you bring three of that circumstances, probably this which are requiring some handling, not just appear-disappear and not each-other related ? :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow that at all? What do you mean by "bring three of that circumstances"?

Comment: There're a lot of circumstances when window is resizing it's "view", i'd like to learn a few of them. From my experience there's nothing catastrophic that could happen and i'm very eager to learn.